# Solving a system of ODEs over a Dynamic Graph

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, graphs-and-networks, dynamic

I want to solve a system of ODEs over a dynamical graph. That is, vertices and edges might be added or removed over time and I want to keep solving it. Is it possible to do it using `NDSolve`?

For instance, imagine I want to solve the following system of ODEs

```
solf = NDSolve[{
   f'[t] == -ag.f[t],
   f[0] == ConstantArray[0, Length[ag]]
   }, f, {t, 0, 10}]
```

where `ag` is a random connectivity matrix related to each vertex. Take it to be given by

```
ag = AdjacencyMatrix[RandomGraph[RandomInteger[{5, 10}, 2]]]
```

Now, naturally I want `ag` to be a function of time as well, with entry values and number of rows changing over time, but I suspect my solution `solf` wouldn't work, since at some times I might have more entries and at other times fewer.

The main motivation behind this question is to implement a version of proliferating cells that interact with each other. Some might die and some might divide, therefore I need to implement this dynamical scenario while solving the ODEs for live cells. From a 2D mesh, I can get the adjacency graph and the connectivity properties I need, hence my problem simplifies to the one presented above. I could implement this in a trickier manner by using `For`, but I wonder if this has been done before.

Any ideas?

Comment: Restart the integration at each birth/death event with a new system model?  (In other words, I don't think the built-in function support this sort of dynamic behavior, so you'll have to code it yourself.)

Comment: Yes, I believe that might be the only solution. Do you know if it's possible to set the integration step on `NDSolve`?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about [`"FixedStep"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveFixedStep.html), but I had in mind using `WhenEvent[]` and `"StopIntegration"`. I can imagine `WhenEvent[]` not being convenient, though.

Comment: I suppose that if the number of vertices is small, you could start with all present and future vertices and set approriate interaction coefficients to zero/nonzero when a vertex dies/is born. One could also have a discrete 0/1 variables that indicate when a vertex is dead/alive; this could also be coded as a diagonal matrix with 0s and 1s on the diagonal.  If there are a large number of vertices and only a few are alive at any given time (e.g. you evolve the system through many generations), then this is unlikely to be efficient.