# Square root problem

Tags: differential-equations, system-variables, equation-solving

Consider the following code

```
NDSolveValue[{
  x'[t] == x[t]^a,
  x[0] == 0
  }, x, {t, 0, 10}]
```

which solves the equation $x'(t)=x(t)^a$, for some exponent $a$, with $x(0)=0$. If I want to solve two identical equations, I can simply add a new initial condition

```
NDSolveValue[{
  x'[t] == x[t]^a,
  x[0] == {0, 0}
  }, x, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I want to solve this system when $a=1/2$ (square root), however this doesn't work for more than one equation and I get, among others, the error

```
"NDSolveValue::nbnum1: The function value {0,0}==0 is not True or False when the arguments are {0.,{0.,0.},{0.,0.}}."
```

Why is that? If I pick any $a\geq 1$ it works as intended. Why is it suddenly interpreting the right hand side as a scalar for $a<1$? In the one equation case, square root works. Any ideas?

**Edit and motivation:** I want to mimic the following code

```
NDSolveValue[{x1'[t] == Sqrt[x1[t]], x2'[t] == Sqrt[x2[t]], 
  x1[0] == x2[0] == 0}, {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

and the reason I'm using this is because I would like to generate a big list of equations. For $a\geq 1$, at least, the main difference between this approach and mine is that here I get a list of two interpolating functions with scalar outputs, and in my case I get one interpolating function with 2 output dimensions.

In other words, what is the best way to solve
$$
x_1'(t)=\sqrt{x_1(t)}, x_2'(t)=\sqrt{x_2(t)}, \cdots,x_n'(t)=\sqrt{x_n(t)}\\
$$
for an arbitrary $n$? The main reason I'm interested in this approach is because it's what I use to solve a system like this
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1'(t)\\
x_2'(t)\\
\vdots\\
x_n'(t)
\end{pmatrix}=A
f\begin{pmatrix}
x_1(t)\\
x_2(t)\\
\vdots\\
x_n(t)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A$ is some $n\times n$ matrix and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$. In this specific case, $A$ is the identity matrix and $f$ maps the square root.

Comment: "If I want to solve two identical equations, I can simply add a new initial condition" - I don't understand that at all, as I don't understand what you mean by `x[0] = {0, 0}` in your initial conditions. I suspect that `NDSolveValue` is having the same problem interpreting what you mean. Also, exactly what code generates the error you saw?

Comment: @MarcoB Here's my motivation: Imagine I want to solve a system of $n$ ODEs that are dependent on each other (say we're measuring the signal of $n$ cells interacting in a tissue, for example). I noticed that a 'compact' way of doing that in Mathematica, when the system of ODEs is really big, is to define an adjacency matrix and treating all functions as a list. For example, see what I did in this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224470/solving-a-system-of-odes-over-a-dynamic-graph Also, see the edit section, to see what I mean

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is to solve the ODE for many different initial conditions "all at once"? If so, you can do something like: a = 1/2; NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == x[t]^a, x[0] == #}, x, {t, 0, 10}] & /@
  Range[0, 1, 0.1] where the Range is just used here to specify all the different initial conditions.

Comment: I don't understand. Even your very first system: NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == x[t]^a, x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 10}] does not work without assigning a value to $a$.

Comment: @bills Of course not, but the point is that when I assign $a$ to some value, I can solve multiple equations in my second system, but only for $a\geq 1$.

Comment: I've added an entire motivation section to expose clearly why I'm interested in this approach. My feeling is that 'NDSolve' is not consistent in interpreting 'Sqrt' as a map, while exponents greater or equal than $1$ work fine.

Comment: I think the problems is that `Sqrt` is a multivalued function. If you use `Surd` (this gives a real value) instead of `Sqrt`, then the following works: `NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == Surd[x[t], 2], x[0] == {0, 1}}, x, {t, 0, 10}]`

Comment: @DanielHuber that's it! Thank you so much, I didn't know about `Surd`

Comment: Your code works as is. Don't have an explanation for all the messages, but the code produces the correct result despite all the whining.

Comment: Don't you get a `NDSolveValue::ecboo` error, too? That was the key for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `a = 1/2`, the problem is that the discontinuity processing automatically handles the singularity in the `x[t]^a` power (`Sqrt[x[t]]`) by setting up an event when `x[t] == 0`.  Unfortunately, it doesn't notice that `x[t]` is a vector quantity, so that the event testing causes a slew of errors.  The most telling one is `NDSolveValue::ecboo`, which mentions an "event" and clearly points to some trouble with the discontinuity processing.

A fix is to turn `"DiscontinuityProcessing"` off:

```
ClearAll[x, t, a];
Block[{a = 1/2},
 foo = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == x[t]^a, x[0] == {0, 0}}, x, {t, 0, 10}, 
   Method -> {Automatic, "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> None}]
 ]
```

[image]